# Flutter: After refresing my data is showing

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, flutter-animation, flutter-test

when I click on  address textformField then a  open a alert dialog box,In this alert dialog box I have Dropdown, when i choose any dropdown item then that time not showing data, when i refresh the page then my data is showing on dropdown show.

This is my code

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:io';


import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:easy_localization/easy_localization.dart';
import 'package:http_interceptor/http/intercepted_client.dart';
import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';
import 'package:multi_image_picker2/multi_image_picker2.dart';
import 'package:readmore/readmore.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

class ViewEditProfile extends StatefulWidget {
  const ViewEditProfile({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _ViewEditProfileState createState() => _ViewEditProfileState();
}

class _ViewEditProfileState extends State<ViewEditProfile> {
  var _fullNameController = TextEditingController();
  var _emailController = TextEditingController();
  var _dobController = TextEditingController();
  var _genderController = TextEditingController();
  var _addressController = TextEditingController();
  var _adharController = TextEditingController();
  var _panController = TextEditingController();
  var userPhoneNumber;

  List? stateList = [];
  List? districtList = [];
  List? tehsilList = [];
  List? villageList = [];

  String? _selectedState;
  String? _selectedDistrict;
  String? _selectedTehsil;
  String? _selectedVillage;

  DatabaseService db = DatabaseService();


  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    // _loadSharedPrefs();
    getGeoPointsDetailsUsingType();
    // genderFunct();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: MyAppbarNoSearch(),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Container(
          child: Column(
            children: [
            Container(
            color: mPrimaryColor,
            height: MediaQuery
                .of(context)
                .size
                .height / 23,
            width: MediaQuery
                .of(context)
                .size
                .width,
            child: Row(
              children: [
                SizedBox(
                  width: 15,
                ),
                InkWell(
                  onTap: () {
                    Navigator.pop(context);
                  },
                  child: Container(
                    height: MediaQuery
                        .of(context)
                        .size
                        .height / 23,
                    width: 30,
                    child: Icon(
                      Icons.arrow_back_ios_rounded,
                      size: 20,
                      color: whitetext,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Expanded(
                  child: Text(
                    "VIEW EDIT PROFILE".tr(),
                    style: headingWhite(),
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  width: 40,
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            height: MediaQuery
                .of(context)
                .size
                .height / 3.9,
            width: MediaQuery
                .of(context)
                .size
                .width,
            // width: 110,
            // height: 110,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(boxShadow: [
              BoxShadow(
                color: grey,
                offset: const Offset(
                  0,
                  5.0,
                ),
                blurRadius: 5.0,
                spreadRadius: 0,
              ), //BoxShadow
              BoxShadow(
                color: Colors.white,
                offset: const Offset(0.0, 0.0),
                blurRadius: 0.0,
                spreadRadius: 0.0,
              ), //BoxShadow
            ]),
            child: Column(
                children: [
            Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 7, right: 15),
            child: GestureDetector(
              onTap: () {
                isEnableFun(context);
              },
              child: Container(
                height: 24,
                child: Align(
                  alignment: Alignment.topRight,
             
                  child: isEnable
                      ? Text(
                    'UPDATE',
                    style: cardTitleGreen(),
                  )
                      : Text(
                    'EDIT',
                    style: cardTitleGreen(),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            children: [
              Container(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(2),
          
                width: 120,
                height: 120,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  border:
                  Border.all(color: mPrimaryColor, width: 1.0),

                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(60),
              
                ),
                child: isEnable == false
                    ? Container(
                  margin: EdgeInsets.all(1),
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(60),
                      image: DecorationImage(
                          image: NetworkImage(
                              "https://www.aiyd.org/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/no-image-icon-hi-1.png"),
                          fit: BoxFit.cover)),
                )
                    : Stack(
                  children: [
                    Container(
                      margin: EdgeInsets.all(1),
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          borderRadius:
                          BorderRadius.circular(60),
                          image: DecorationImage(
                              image: NetworkImage(
                                  "https://www.aiyd.org/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/no-image-icon-hi-1.png"),
                              fit: BoxFit.cover)),
                    ),
                    Positioned(
                      top: 0,
                      right: 0,
                      child: InkWell(
                        onTap: () {
                          // shopLogoLoadAssets();
                          getImage();
                        },
                        child: Container(
                          height: 40,
                          width: 40,
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            shape: BoxShape.circle,
                            border: Border.all(
                                width: 4, color: Colors.white),
                            color: mPrimaryColor,
                          ),
                          child: Icon(
                            Icons.edit,
                            color: Colors.white,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(
                width: 25,
              ),
              Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [

                  //star address part
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                        top: 14, left: 23, right: 23),
                    child: Theme(
                      data: ThemeData(
                        disabledColor: cardTextbgYellow,
                      ),
                      child: TextFormField(
                        readOnly: true,
                        controller: _addressController,
                        minLines: 2,
                        maxLines: 3,
                        keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
                        cursorColor: mPrimaryColor,
                        style: TextStyle(color: mPrimaryColor),
                        enabled: isEnable,
                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                          prefixIconConstraints: BoxConstraints(
                            minWidth: 23,
                          ),
                          prefixIcon: Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                              right: 17,
                            ),
                            child: Icon(
                              Icons.location_on_outlined,
                              color: mPrimaryColor,
                            ),
                          ),
                          hintText: "Your Address",
                          hintStyle: cardTitleGreen(),
                          enabledBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                            borderSide:
                            BorderSide(color: cardTextbg.withOpacity(0.5)),
                          ),
                          focusedBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                            borderSide:
                            BorderSide(color: cardTextbg.withOpacity(0.5)),
                          ),
                        ),
                        onTap: () {
                          setState(() {
                            showAddressDialog();
                          });
                        },
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
//end address partpan part
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 20,
                  ),

                  isEnable
                      ? CustomButton(
                    text: "SAVE".tr(),
                    textColor: Colors.white,
                    gradient: buttongradient,
                    icon: Icons.arrow_forward_ios_outlined,
                    iconColor: Colors.white,
                    onPressed: () {},
                  )
                      : Container(),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 20,
                  ),
                ],
              )
            ],),
      ]  ),),]),)
    
    
    )
    ,
    );
  }

  getGeoPointsDetailsUsingType() async {
    db.getGeoPointDetailsByType("State").then((onValue) =>
    {
      setState(() {
        stateList = onValue;
        print("line 1");
        print("object::: " + stateList!.length.toString());
        print("line 2");
      })
    });
  }

  getGeoPointsDetailsUsingId(String id, String type) async {
    db.getGeoPointDetailsById(id).then((onValue) =>
    {
      print(type),
      setState(() {
        print("id:: " + id);
        if (type == "District") {
          districtList = onValue;
          print("districtList:: " + districtList.toString());
        } else if (type == "Tehsil") {
          tehsilList = onValue;
        } else if (type == "VillagePanchayat") {
          villageList = onValue;
        }
      })
    });
  }

  showAddressDialog() {
    showDialog(
        barrierDismissible: false,
        context: context,
        builder: (context) =>
            AlertDialog(
              insetPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10),
              scrollable: true,
              actions: [
                Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: [
                    CustomButton2(
                      text: "OK",
                      onPressed: () {
                        Navigator.of(context).pop();
                      },
                      gradient: buttongradient,
                    )
                  ],
                )
              ],
              content: Container(
                width: MediaQuery
                    .of(context)
                    .size
                    .width,
                child: Column(
                  children: [
                    Row(
                      children: [
                        Expanded(
                          child: Container(
                            height: 30,
                            padding:
                            EdgeInsets.only(top: 0, left: 4, bottom: 0),
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                                    topLeft: Radius.circular(8),
                                    bottomLeft: Radius.circular(8)),
                                border: Border.all(
                                    color: mPrimaryColorLight, width: 0.5)),
                            child: DropdownButtonHideUnderline(
                              child: DropdownButton<String>(
                                focusColor: Colors.red,
                                hint: Text(
                                  "State".tr(),
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                      fontSize: 13,
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
                                  overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                                ),
                                value: _selectedState,
                                isExpanded: true,
                                elevation: 2,
                                icon: Icon(
                                  // Add this
                                  Icons.arrow_drop_down, // Add this
                                  color: mPrimaryColorLight, // Add this
                                ),
                                items: stateList!.length > 0
                                    ? List.generate(
                                  stateList!.length,
                                      (index) =>
                                      DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                                        value:
                                        "${stateList![index]['referenceId']}",
                                        child: new Text(
                                          stateList![index]['name'],
                                          style: TextStyle(
                                              fontSize: 13,
                                              fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
                                          overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                )
                                    : ["Select State"].map((option) {
                                  return DropdownMenuItem(
                                    child: Text(
                                      "$option",
                                      style: TextStyle(
                                          fontSize: 13,
                                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
                                      overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                                    ),
                                    value: option,
                                  );
                                }).toList(),
                                onChanged: (String? val) {
                                  setState(() {
                                    _selectedState = val;
                                    print(_selectedState);

                                    if (stateList!.length > 0) {
                                      getGeoPointsDetailsUsingId(
                                          _selectedState!, "District");
                                    }
                                  });
                                },
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        Expanded(
                          child: Container(
                            height: 30,
                            padding:
                            EdgeInsets.only(top: 0, left: 4, bottom: 0),
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                border: Border.all(
                                    color: mPrimaryColorLight, width: 0.5)),
                            child: DropdownButtonHideUnderline(
                              child: DropdownButton<String>(
                                focusColor: Colors.red,
                                hint: Text(
                                  "District".tr(),
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                      fontSize: 13,
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
                                  overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                                ),
                                value: _selectedDistrict,
                                icon: Icon(
                                  // Add this
                                  Icons.arrow_drop_down, // Add this
                                  color: mPrimaryColorLight, // Add this
                                ),
                                isExpanded: true,
                                elevation: 2,
                                items: districtList!.length > 0
                                    ? List.generate(
                                    districtList!.length,
                                        (index) =>
                                        DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                                          value:
                                          "${districtList![index]['referenceId']}",
                                          child: new Text(
                                            districtList?[index]['name'],
                                            style: TextStyle(
                                                fontSize: 13,
                                                fontWeight:
                                                FontWeight.w500),
                                            overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                                          ),
                                        ))
                                    : ["Select District"].map((option) {
                                  return DropdownMenuItem(
                                    child: Text(
                                      "$option",
                                      style: TextStyle(
                                          fontSize: 13,
                                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
                                      overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                                    ),
                                    value: option,
                                  );
                                }).toList(),
                                onChanged: (String? val) {
                                  setState(() {
                                    _selectedDistrict = val;

                                    if (districtList!.length > 0) {
                                      getGeoPointsDetailsUsingId(
                                          _selectedDistrict!, "Tehsil");
                                    }
                                  });
                                },
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        Expanded(
                          child: Container(
                            height: 30,
                            padding:
                            EdgeInsets.only(top: 0, left: 4, bottom: 0),
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                border: Border.all(
                                    color: mPrimaryColorLight, width: 0.5)),
                            child: DropdownButtonHideUnderline(
                              child: DropdownButton<String>(
                                focusColor: Colors.red,
                                hint: Text(
                                  "Tehsil".tr(),
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                      fontSize: 13,
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
                                  overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                                ),
                                value: _selectedTehsil,
                                isExpanded: true,
                                elevation: 2,
                                icon: Icon(
                                  // Add this
                                  Icons.arrow_drop_down, // Add this
                                  color: mPrimaryColorLight, // Add this
                                ),
                                items: tehsilList!.length > 0
                                    ? List.generate(
                                    tehsilList!.length,
                                        (index) =>
                                        DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                                            value:
                                            "${tehsilList![index]['referenceId']}",
                                            child: new Text(
                                              tehsilList![index]['name'],
                                              style: TextStyle(
                                                  fontSize: 13,
                                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
                                              overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                                            )))
                                    : ["Select Tehsil"].map((option) {
                                  return DropdownMenuItem(
                                    child: Text(
                                      "$option",
                                      style: TextStyle(
                                          fontSize: 13,
                                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
                                      overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                                    ),
                                    value: option,
                                  );
                                }).toList(),
                                onChanged: (String? val) {
                                  setState(() {
                                    _selectedTehsil = val;

                                    if (tehsilList!.length > 0) {
                                      getGeoPointsDetailsUsingId(
                                          _selectedTehsil!, "VillagePanchayat");
                                    }
                                  });
                                },
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        Expanded(
                          child: Container(
                            height: 30,
                            padding:
                            EdgeInsets.only(top: 0, left: 4, bottom: 0),
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                                    topRight: Radius.circular(8),
                                    bottomRight: Radius.circular(8)),
                                border: Border.all(
                                    color: mPrimaryColorLight, width: 0.5)),
                            child: DropdownButtonHideUnderline(
                              child: DropdownButton<String>(
                                focusColor: Colors.red,
                                hint: Text(
                                  "Village".tr(),
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                      fontSize: 13,
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
                                  overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                                ),
                                value: _selectedVillage,
                                isExpanded: true,
                                elevation: 2,
                                icon: Icon(
                                  // Add this
                                  Icons.arrow_drop_down, // Add this
                                  color: mPrimaryColorLight, // Add this
                                ),
                                items: villageList!.length > 0
                                    ? List.generate(
                                    villageList!.length,
                                        (index) =>
                                        DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                                            value:
                                            "${villageList![index]['referenceId']}",
                                            child: new Text(
                                              villageList![index]['name'],
                                              style: TextStyle(
                                                  fontSize: 13,
                                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
                                              overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                                            )))
                                    : ["Select Village"].map((option) {
                                  return DropdownMenuItem(
                                    child: Text(
                                      "$option",
                                      style: TextStyle(
                                          fontSize: 13,
                                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
                                      overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                                    ),
                                    value: option,
                                  );
                                }).toList(),
                                onChanged: (String? val) {
                                  setState(() {
                                    _selectedVillage = val;

                                    // getGeoPointsDetailsUsingId(
                                    //     _selectedVillage!);
                                  });
                                },
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 5,
                    ),
                   
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ));
  }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to wrap your dialog with StatefulBuilder

```
StatefulBuilder(builder: (BuildContext context, StateSetter setState) {
     //Your AlertDialog
}
```

Comment: Thank you But I am facing one new problem when I choose state then my district data load in list of variable but I think my district list data not take in dropdown but when i come back and again open dialog box then my all data i showing show how to fix it.

Comment: Try to wrap this `tehsilList = onValue;` with seState instead of whole `if`

Comment: My data is loading in the data of the variable in which I am loading is not showing even after clicking on the dropdown button, when I am coming to the main page from the dialog page and then open the dialog then that  data is showing in dropdownItem

Comment: Have you call setState after selecting district?

Comment: You know my drop down how work, first i choose state ,when i choose state then i take id that value and id goes my service then call district then my district data store in DistrictList, but that District data wanna show my district dropdown.

Comment: if (type == "District") {
        setState(() {
          districtList = onValue;
        }),
            print("districtList" + districtList.toString()),
          } else if (type == "Tehsil") {
           setState(() {
             tehsilList = onValue;
           }),
          } else if (type == "VillagePanchayat") {
           setState(() {
             villageList = onValue;
           }),
          }            Like this na

Comment: I think the problem is in setState after get the data from service. After you select the State, call seState to update the data, then after get the data from service, call setState again to update the list

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237349/discussion-between-deepak-and-ananda-pramono).